# index database by IS NOT NULL sqlite

Tags: sqlite, indexing, null

I have dataset in Sqlite of the following sort:

| person_id | tax_id | taxes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2000 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 321 | 3000 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL |

So `tax_id` is `NULL` for many observations. I will be often filtering by those where `tax_id is not NULL`, and I'd like to create an index based on that. Is it possible? I don't care about the `tax_id` number itself, I only care this person has a `tax_id`.

The simple answer is to create a new column with `1` if `tax id is not Null` and `0` otherwise, and then index based on this new column. But it does not seem very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Partial Index". You add the WHERE clause at the end.

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_taxes ON taxes(tax_id) WHERE tax_id IS NOT NULL;
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html.

Comment: If I understand partial indices correctly, it would not be indexing any row with a null value. But still, every tax_id would have its own index, is it? It seems it would be more efficient if there were only two index values, 0 and 1.

Comment: So you are not planning to filter on specific tax_id?

Comment: Your might need to reconsider the structure of your schema. The table may not be normalized.

Comment: Indeed, I don't care about any specific tax_id, I only care if its not null or not. Many of the analysis is done on those people with a tax_id. 

And you're right, I should reconsider the structure but I can't do it due to other constraints.

Comment: @Marc de la Barrera i Bardalet The size of the index is not related to the number of different values. An index on tax_id will contain as many rows as an index on a boolean value. The partial index proposed by PChemGuy will contain as many rows as there are NOT NULL values in the table and such index will be actually used by the query planner. A boolean index would not be more efficient.